# Cubic Honeycomb Traverse

Tags: gr.group-theory

Starting at an arbitray cube in an infinite cubic lattice is there a path that visits every cube in every n^3  region in  n^3  steps? I have found 2 or three such traverses for 2^3, but I have yet to work out 3^3.

If such traverses are possible for n>=3, is it possible to construct an algorithm that makes the traverse(s)?

Thanks for your help and interest. :)

Comment: You can likely do an arrangement of cubical shells around a central core.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.17

Comment: I do not understand your question: Do you want existence of a one-to-one lattice path $\mathbb N\longrightarrow \mathbb Z^3$
(with lattice points given by centers of cubes)? 